# Add Delay to Mouseover using Javascript

Tags: javascript, delay, mouseover

I'm using the following script for all my image mouseovers:

```
loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src="1.jpg";
staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src="1-roll,jpg";
```

How can I simply add, say, a second or two delay before it executes the mouseover?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---UPDATE---

Thanks for the replies. Excuse my ignorance when it comes to Javascript. How can I include the timeout piece in the following script?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src="/wp-content/themes/Anna%20Rawson/images/1-blog.jpg";
staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src="/wp-content/themes/Anna%20Rawson/images/1-blog.jpg";
</script>
```

Do I wrap the timeout piece in it's own script tag? Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), an example:

```
var img1 = document.getElementById('my-img');
img1.onmouseover = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.src = 'my-img-2.png';
  }, 1000); // 1000ms = 1s delay
};
```

---

First of all, your code have some mistakes:

- Always write HTML tags in lowercase, not `<SCRIPT>` but `<script>`
- The `langauge` attribute is not a valid attribute, use `type="text/javascript"` instead, or just remove it it isn't required.

And the Image object is not really making an image on the website. It preloads the image, so you can use it on your website without loading it. Like this example:

```
<img src="/img/my-first-img.png" onmouseover="this.src = '/img/heavy-img.png'">
<script>
  var heavyImg = new Image();
  heavyImg.src = '/img/heavy-img.png'; // preload the img
</script>
```

Because we preload the `/img/heavy-img.png` we can directly see the heavy-img if me mouse over the first-img. If we don't preload the img, it will be loaded when we mouse over.

Instead of using an `onmouseover` attribute we use the `onmouseover` event + callback in the JS file. Now we can add a delay:

```
<img src="/img/my-first-img.png" id="my-img">
<script>
  var heavyImg = new Image();
  heavyImg.src = '/img/heavy-img.png'; // preload the img

  var myImg = document.getElementById('my-img'); // get the element with id="my-img" out of the DOM

  // create a mouseover event
  myImg.onmouseover = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.src = '/img/heavy-img.png' // load the img
    }, 1000); // a delay of 1000ms = 1s
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated the post w/ a question. Any way you could help me piece that code in there? Thanks a ton!